# What programming language to use?

Tags: android, ios, programming

What programming language should i use to make an android and IOS application..I'd like to know which ones are easier to learn and ones to help me make a really good application.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Sorry to interrupt, but please see: [Should programming language recommendations be allowed here?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, you can choose from several programming languages that no doubt each have advantages and disadvantages. See [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3950022/5759901) from Stack Overflow.  Download the Android SDK, choose the language you are going to work with and get started.  Publishing apps to Google's Play Store is free.

For iOS, you'll use Apple's XCode software and the programming language is [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) which requires you to develop on a Mac computer.  Publishing to Apple's App Store requires a Developer's account and costs $99 per year.

There is an alternative.  You can create your apps using pure HTML, JavaScript and CSS.  Using cloud services, you can get those apps packaged to work on both platforms with reasonably good support for built-in functions, but will not have full OS integration on either platform. This is accomplished using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

Here is a good [step-by-step guide](https://www.joshmorony.com/the-step-by-step-guide-to-publishing-a-html5-mobile-application-on-app-stores/) for getting started with Cordova.

I have published apps to both stores using Cordova and received zero complaints from users over the time span of more than four years.

As for which language is easier to learn, the author of the Stack Overflow post linked above indicates that Corona is easiest to learn. [Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) is also easy to learn.  As I mentioned, if you want to make apps for iOS that tightly integrate with the OS and device, you will have to use Swift and XCode.

To make very good applications, you will need to develop independently for each platform. I use Cordova because I have been working with HTML / JavaScript / CSS for a very long time, so it's easy for me, and my apps are utilities that require very little integration with the OS and device.